# In React Native, how to make a remote image fit its container while maintaining its aspect ratio

Tags: react-native, image

I'm trying to load remote images and display them into an image component, but I want the component to fit the image.

This is what I have so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 5,
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: undefined,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'blue',
    },
});

function Post({ post }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.view}>
            <Image
                source={{
                    uri: post.image,
                }}
                style={styles.image}
            />
        </View>
    );
}


export default Post;
```

I was reading previous questions and found that I can maintain the aspect ratio by applying these styles:

```
width: '100%',
height: undefined,
aspectRatio: 1,
resizeMode: 'contain',
```

It works; however, the height must be declared as undefined, therefore, some whitespaces appear at the top and bottom of the image.

This is the result I get:

[image: image-view]

How can I make the component fit the image completely without cropping or losing part of the image?

This is an example of an app that does exactly what I want:

[image]

It's the same image, the aspect ratio is maintained and there are no gaps in their image component.

*URL of the image that I'm fetching: https://www.mediacollege.com/video/test-patterns/images/aspect-ratio-circles-1024x768.jpg

Comment: Do you want the image stretched or cropped to fit the container?

Comment: @Abe neither, I want the parent to fit the image completely without any stretching or crop. If the image is, for example: 500x500 then the parent should wrap it and be the same size.

Comment: @Aeross I don't think this will be possible to achieve if the image is larger than the container then it will get cropped in order to fit in or if it is smaller then it will get stretched.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to calculate and set image height dynamically. Something like this:

```js
const ScaledImage = ({ uri }) => {
  const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {
      setImageHeight(Math.round((height * windowWidth) / width));
    });
  }, [uri]);

  return (
    <Image
      style={{ width: '100%', height: imageHeight, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
      source={{
        uri,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```